# Can't remove custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have removed all references to the plugin in the DB and the codebase.
The plugin is currently displayed as "Not installed" in the plugins admin panel.
When I try to remove it by clicking on "remove" in the cog menu I get the usual composer updating message. After this the plugin is still there in the overview.
I can't find any reference to the plugin in the codebase by searching the whole project.

I do get a warning message in the logs: `2024-02-05 16:57:22 [web.WARNING] [craft\services\Plugins::init] Invalid plugin base path: /app/vendor/company/aankoopbonnen/src {"memory":1373240}`

Where is it still finding this path?
And how can I remove it from the project?

Comment: Is the plugin still referenced in the `composer.json`? Possibly as a [path repository](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/plugin-guide.html#path-repository)?

Comment: No, it has been removed from the composer.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add back the plugin to the install directory, then remove it from the control panel normally, Note it is trying to remove the folder but did not find it.

Comment: That will probably work indeed. But where is it still remembering this plugin from? If I could delete that reference surely that would fix it as well?

Comment: You will have to do too much work to fix every place , there would be the composer , the autoload.php inside the vendor directory , if you want to go for this route make sure if you are searching inside your IDE that you include the vendor folder ( As it is ignored most of the time )

Comment: I ended up creating a new plugin with the same name. Then removed the plugin from the interface and then deleted the new plugin from the codebase.
Weird, but it works!